# Android onBackPressed for all activities

Tags: java, android

I have an issue with my Android Studio project. In multipe activities I want to show AlertDialog after user click on back button, but now it means that I have to override onBackPressed() method seven times (in each activity). Is it possible to do that once for all activities?

Comment: Hi! Welcome to StackOverflow. Do you have much experience with Java and class inheritance? Creating a shared parent class that your seven activity classes are derived from would be one place to start.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a single activity with `onBackPressed` overrided:

```
public class OnBackPressedActivity extends Activity {
    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        // do stuff
    }
}
```

And then in your code use not `extends Activity`, but rather `extends OnBackPressedActivity`

Answer (score 3):

You can have a `BaseActivity` and have your other activities extend from the `BaseActivity`. In the `onBackPressed()` method of activities, just call `super.onBackPressed()`

```
class BaseActivity extend AppCompatActivity {
     @Override public void onBackPressed() {
           //your logic here
     }
 }

class MainActivity extends BaseActivity {
     @Override public void onBackPressed() {
         super.onBackPressed()
     }
}
```

In this way, your actual logic will remain at one place. Keep in mind, that you have to override the onBackPressed method in each activity.

Answer (score 0):

Create abstract BaseActivity that will extends AppCompatActivity/Activity
in this activity, override onBackPressed() , and create alertDialog

Now all activity will extent this BaseActivity only.

Answer (score 0):

I won't inherit from a "base class". Programming isn't always code reuse. And if, code reusing by inheritance is an anti pattern. As you will have seven onBackPressed() methods you will have seven onCreate() and so on. What you may do, is to create a class to have your onBackPressed logic to call from your seven onBackPressed() from every activity. Delegate common logic to a helper class.

Comment: Isn't the whole point of inheritance code reuse and polymorphism?

Comment: @Ezio Yes, when you are working on your code (e.g. a complex data structure for your business logic). When it comes to use (complex) APIs, it is not a good idea to extend to a new hierarchy with the provided by the API. Anyway, in this particular case (Android UI) it is more a question of preferences.

Comment: Ah, it makes sense.